# Нужно в input вставлять выбранные города

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть такой выпадающий список с чекбоксами .filter_dropdown

```
<div class="filter_select_wrapp">
    <div class="filter_select_title">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Город" readonly="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="filter_dropdown">
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked="" name="">
                <span>Город 1</span>
              </label>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked="" name="">
                <span>Город 2</span>
              </label>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked="" name="">
                <span>Город 3</span>
              </label>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Нужно чтобы названия городов вставлялись в input в блоке .filter_select_title. Если чекбокс .filter_dropdown отключен то этот город из input в .filter_select_title должен быть удален.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, отловили клик, перебрали в блоке выбранные checkbox, вставили в нужный input выбранные значения

```js
$(".filter_dropdown input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
  valTowns = "";
  $(".filter_dropdown input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(indx, element){
   valTowns += $(this).val();
  });
  $("input[name=listtowns]").val( valTowns);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter_select_wrapp">
    <div class="filter_select_title">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Город" name="listtowns" readonly="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="filter_dropdown">
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked="" name="">
                <span>Город 1</span>
              </label>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked="" name="">
                <span>Город 2</span>
              </label>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked="" name="">
                <span>Город 3</span>
              </label>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все получилось )

Answer (score 0):

```js
let checkbox = $(".filter_dropdown .checkbox");
let s = "";
checkbox.find("input:checked").each(function(){
  s += $(this).parent().find("span").text() + ", ";
});
$(".filter_select_title input").val(s);
checkbox.each(function(el){
  let element = $(this); 
  $(this).find("input").click(function(){
    let st = "";
    checkbox.find("input:checked").each(function(){
      st += $(this).parent().find("span").text() + ", ";
    });
    $(".filter_select_title input").val(st);
    if ($(this).attr("checked") != "checked"){
       $(this).attr("checked","");
    }
    else {
      $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter_select_wrapp">
    <div class="filter_select_title">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Город" readonly="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="filter_dropdown">
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked name="">
                <span>Город 1</span>
              </label>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="">
                <span>Город 2</span>
              </label>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Y" checked name="">
                <span>Город 3</span>
              </label>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```